# Android Social networks sdk which use native libs

Tags: android, facebook, linkedin-api, social-networking

I know about socialauth-android, but it uses oauth and can't use already installed user's social network apps - but facebook sdk can do it, or I need to use outh requests - better use native methods

Maybe you can advice any lib which contain native libs and give interface to login and share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) it uses facebook-sdk and you can use other methods from it, or you can post photo directly to instagram app.

It contains most popular networks, just check it - maybe it helps you